# Symfony forms, error bubbling

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with forms' error bubbling.
One field in my form is defined like this:

```
$formBuilder->add('title','text',
   'required'  => true, 
   'error_bubbling' => false,
   )
)
```

I would like to add a validator like this to this field:

```
/**
  * @Assert\True(message = "Bad title.")
  */
public function getTitleCorrect()
{
    /* ... */     
    return false;
}
```

It works ok, but the error message shows up on top of the form, not in the field row.

In the Twig template this error message is rendered by `{{form_errors(form)}}` as a global error. When I use `{{form_errors(form.title)}}`, it does not print my error.

What can I do to change the assignment of the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Messages are attached to a field only when validator is attached to corresponding property.
Your validator is attached to a method of the class so error is indeed global.

You should to something like that:

```
use ...\TitleValidator as AssertTitleValid;

class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @AssertTitleValid
     */
    private $title;
}
```

And create your own TitleValidator class.

Answer (score 4):

'error_bubbling' is `false` by default unless it is set to `true` or form is compound.

Besides error might be bubbled up if there is some mismatch between form field and validated property/method, like you have in your example or if different case is used (`snake_case` for form field and `$camelCase` for validated property).

In this case you may use 'error_mapping' in your form class:

```
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     *
     * @throws AccessException
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => YourEntity::class,
            'error_mapping' => [
                'entityProperty' => 'form_field_1',
                'entityMethod' => 'form_field_2',
            ],
        ]);
    }
```